# How to have background gradient fill entire page?

Tags: html, css, viewport, linear-gradients

I am just recently getting started with learning HTML/CSS, and I'm pretty confused as to how to make this linear gradient I have for the background fit the entire page. I've poked around, and I can't quite seem to find a thread that fits my exact situation.

I currently have it set so that the gradient fills the entire viewport and also scales with the browser window size. **However, I am curious to know how to make the gradient not follow me wherever I scroll with the viewport, but have the entire gradient fill the page (past the viewport, not locking with the viewport or following me wherever I scroll).**

So, if you were to scroll all the way to the right, for example, you would see what the "rightmost" area of the gradient would be, not simply the entire gradient that I've set (nor a repeating gradient). I'm sorry if I'm not being clear. Thank you for your time.

```
<head>
    <style>
        html {
            height: auto;
        }

        body {
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, pink, white);
            height: auto;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        div {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }

        .blue {
            background-color: blue;
        }

        .yellow {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .magenta {
            background-color: magenta;
        }

        .sand-brown {
            background-color: rgb(214, 176, 93);
            /*height: 5000px;*/
            width: 5000px;
        }

        .sand-brown2 {
            background-color: rgb(214, 176, 93);
            height: 5000px;
            /*width: 5000px;*/
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="magenta"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="sand-brown"></div>
    <div class="sand-brown2"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing here is oveflow. Your element are overflowing the body and the size of the gradient fit the size of the `body` then it's getting propagated to the root element and repeated. To avoid this you may need to add another container that you make `inline-block`.

```css
.container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, pink, white);
  display: inline-block;
}

.container > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}

div.sand-brown {
  background-color: rgb(214, 176, 93);
  /*height: 5000px;*/
  width: 5000px;
}

div.sand-brown2 {
  background-color: rgb(214, 176, 93);
  height: 5000px;
  /*width: 5000px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="magenta"></div>
  <br>
  <div class="sand-brown"></div>
  <div class="sand-brown2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for. Could you elaborate more on what the issue is? I don't quite understand why adding an inline-block element to contain all these elements and the gradient makes this the case. Also - why does changing "div.sand-brown" to simply ".sand-brown" make everything different? If I'm applying these sand-brown classes to a div element anyway, don't those 2 classes mean the exact same thing in this case??

Comment: @minorproblem (1) inline-block unlike block element will fit its content (width = width of content) and block element are always 100% width so element are ovelowing the body BUT the new container is expanding to fit its content (2) for the classes it a matter of specificity, I added div to make it more specific than `.container > div` because this one is setting height and width and using only a class is not enough to override it, you will need at least a class+element

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the gradient attribute to the *html* element instead of *body* element.

So instead of this:

```
<head>
<style>
    html {
        height: auto;
    }

    body {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, pink, white);
        height: auto;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

You should have this:

```
<head>
<style>
    html {
        height: auto;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, pink, white);
    }

    body {
        height: auto;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `background-size` setting which is large enough to cover all of your content, like `background-size: 5100px 5500px;` in your case:

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, pink, white);
  background-size: 5100px 5500px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.magenta {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.sand-brown {
  background-color: rgb(214, 176, 93);
  /*height: 5000px;*/
  width: 5000px;
}

.sand-brown2 {
  background-color: rgb(214, 176, 93);
  height: 5000px;
  /*width: 5000px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="yellow"></div>
<br>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="magenta"></div>
<br>
<div class="sand-brown"></div>
<div class="sand-brown2"></div>
```